# create 'like button' that appears on each post?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok first off, I'm fairly new to SQL and PHP. I have a database setup, and I am able to input entries consisting of 3 fields in an HTML form, and have those entries appear on my site. However, I need a 'like button' that will appear on each post, and the idea is the like button will +1 count a counter only for that particular post. I've search all over and being that I'm new, I seem to have a hard time finding what is the right way to do this? I have read similar questions and it looked like people were responding with parsing? I've also read about using hidden fields for comparison on the HTML form being submitted? I can't figure the syntax on that either :/ I'm not advanced enough to apply ideas to my code and I've come here for help on how to get this 'Like button.'

I'm basically looking for something exactly like what is on StackOverflow, where a like button is created along with the post, and is able to only update a +1 counter for the particular post being clicked.

My site currently consists of an admin.php(includes HTML form) page, an index.php(displaying database output), and insert.php(for database insertion), and I've been trying all kinds of ideas using an insert2.php combined with the insert.php.

Any help or comments will be much appreciated. I've found a lot of great help already on this site.  Please let me know if I need to post any code to make it easier, or easier on myself lol.

Thanks all.

Comment: _I can't figure the syntax on that_. So, What is syntax?

Comment: WHAT code ??????????

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking for..? Is how to create a like button that is proprietary for each post. Did I not ask the question correctly?

Comment: Why not create some code? We don't want to give you an answer that doesn't work. Think of the code like submitting a form except that you're just clicking a button only instead of typing and clicking a button.

Comment: I have three fields on my form, that are going into my database; entry, price, and description. When I create a post, I have a like button that appears on the post, but I cannot figure out how to isolate each like button for each post. What I imagine, is having my (php/sql)code pull whatever is typed into the 'entry' field on my form, read to create a like button that updates a column in my database, where the data from 'entry' is inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

First make a table for each user linking post with fields user_id, likes, post_id

Now all you have to do is if user like a certain post populate this table,
with likes field 1, and for unlike likes field with 0

In your loop on view add this code

```
 <a href="#" class="likeUserPost" id="like<?php echo $userpost['updates_id']; ?>" updateId="<?php echo $userpost['updates_id']; ?>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ></span> 
<?php if($userpost['islike']=='yes'){echo "UnVote";}else{echo "Vote";} ?></a>
```

jQuery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click','.likeUserPost',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var base_url='<?php echo base_url();?>';
    var user_id ='<?php echo $current_user_id; ?>';
    var updates_id=$(this).attr('updateId');
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:base_url+'home_content/updateLike',
        data:{user_id:user_id,update_id:updates_id},
        success:function(data){
           var res= JSON.parse(data);
            if(res.likecode=="unlike"){
               var totalLike=res.totalcount;
                $('#countID'+updates_id+'').html(totalLike);
                $('#vote'+updates_id+'').html('Vote');
            }
            else{
                 $('#countID'+updates_id+'').html(res.totalcount);
                $('#vote'+updates_id+'').html('UnVote');
            }
        }
    });

  });  

</script>
```

Php Code I am using codeigniter so in my model

```
function updateLike($user_id,$update_id){
        // print_r($update_id);exit;
        $sql=$this->db->query("SELECT * from updates_like where user_id='$user_id' AND  updates_id='$update_id'");
        $data=$sql->row();
        if(empty($data)){
            $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $likeData = array('totallike' =>'1',
                'created_date'=>$date,
                'user_id'=>$user_id,
                'updates_id'=>$update_id
                 );
                $this->db->insert('updates_like',$likeData);
                $returnData = array('likecode' =>'like' , 'totalcount'=>$this->totalLikeCount($update_id));
            }
        else{
            $like=$data->totallike;
            $newLike= 1-$like;
            $this->db->set('totallike',$newLike);
            $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
            $this->db->where('updates_id',$update_id);

            $this->db->update('updates_like');
            if($newLike==0){
                $returnData = array('likecode' =>'unlike' , 'totalcount'=>$this->totalLikeCount($update_id));
            }
            else{
                $returnData = array('likecode' =>'like' , 'totalcount'=>$this->totalLikeCount($update_id));
            }

        }
        return $returnData;
    }
```

This is my Controller

```
public function updateLike(){
    $user_id=$this->current_user_id;
    $update_id=$this->input->post('update_id');
    $a=$this->home_content_model->updateLike($user_id,$update_id);
    print_r(json_encode($a));

}
```

Comment: I Hope You Can Get Some Idea From Here

Comment: Ok, I am using Dreamwaver and Notepad++. I put the code above and received these errors:


Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in C:\xampp\index.php on line 115

Notice: Undefined variable: update_id in C:\xampp\index.php on line
116

Notice: Undefined variable: update_id in C:\xampp\index.php on line 117

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\index.php on line 117

Comment: You have to send an array to your view first. 
remove php tag on that view 
send an array as required

Comment: i was just trying to give you an idea :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm still trying to put it together.